# Custom Model Binding on Interface returning empty ModelName

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have the interface `IInterface` and the class `Concrete` which implements it

I have a view

```
@model IEnumerable<IInterface>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x[i])
}
<span id="result"></span>
```

an editor template `Concrete.cshtml`

```
@model Concrete
@Ajax.BeginForm("Action", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" })
{
    @Html.Hidden("ModelType", Model.GetType())
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

with action:

```
public string Action(IInterface interface) { return "success"; }
```

and a model binder:

```
public class MyModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override CreateModel(
        ControllerContext controllerContext, 
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext, 
        Type modelType)
    {
        var typeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(
                            bindingContext.ModelName + ".ModelType"
                        );

        ...
```

I've used this before with the `IInterface` within a ViewModel and it worked fine, however, now when I submit my Ajax form `bindingContext.ModelName` is empty.

Examining `ValueProvider` in debugger I can see that it contains a `FormValueProvider` who's `_values` contains the key `[0].Interface.ModelType`.

Using the Immediate Window I can confirm calling `.GetValue("[0].Interface.ModelType")` returns the appropriate `typeValue`.

How can I either get `bindingContext.ModelName` to not be empty or how can I get the string `"[0].Interface.ModelType"` I need?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better practice to implement the interface as your model type?

Comment: '@model IInterface' instead of '@model Concrete'

Comment: I don't think that will work because I have several things which implement `IInterface` which each have their own Editor Template.

Comment: Now I think I understand a little better.

Comment: Can you box x=> x[i] by doing x=>(Concrete)x[i]?

Comment: Nope, because it may not be `Concrete` it could be another type which implements `IInterface`, besides it wouldn't help with the Model Binding, which is where I'm having the problem :(

Comment: You can always to a GetType to do the boxing...I'm more interested in seeing if the boxing solves your problem in the short term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a hacky solution which is by no means satisfactory:

```
var typeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + ".ModelType");

if (typeValue == null)
{
    var enumerable = (IEnumerable)bindingContext.ValueProvider;

    var formValueProvider = enumerable.OfType<FormValueProvider>().Single();

    var field = typeof(NameValueCollectionValueProvider).GetField(
                    "_values", 
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance
                );

    var dictionary = (IDictionary)field.GetValue(formValueProvider);

    var keys = (IEnumerable<string>)dictionary.Keys;

    var key = keys.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EndsWith(".ModelType"));

    typeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);
}
```